# Android Badge on Button

Tags: android, badge

Here is my code for xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#F8F8F8">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relative_buttons"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dp_10"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/dp_10"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dp_5"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <com.hyper.barcodeapp.customClass.CustomButton
            android:id="@+id/btn_home"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/home_sel"
            android:text="@string/home"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="@dimen/sp_16" />


        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/frame"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btn_home"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <com.hyper.barcodeapp.customClass.CustomButton
                android:id="@+id/btn_promotions"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/promo"
                android:text="@string/promotions"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textColor="@android:color/tab_indicator_text"
                android:textSize="@dimen/sp_16" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_badge"
                android:layout_width="15dp"
                android:layout_height="15dp"
                android:layout_alignRight="@id/btn_promotions"
                android:layout_alignTop="@id/btn_promotions"
                android:layout_gravity="top|right"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/dp_1"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dp_1"
                android:background="@drawable/badge_circle"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="@dimen/dp_3"
                android:text="10"
                android:textSize="5sp" />

        </FrameLayout>


        <com.hyper.barcodeapp.customClass.CustomButton
            android:id="@+id/btn_search_code"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/frame"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/search"
            android:text="@string/search_code"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="@android:color/tab_indicator_text"
            android:textSize="@dimen/sp_16" />


    </RelativeLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/child_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/relative_buttons"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dp_5"
        android:layout_weight="8">

    </FrameLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Look at the code clearly, if "txt_badge" is a button I can see Badge like icon on "btn_promotions", but if I use Textview instead of button, "txt_badge" is not shown in layout, what can be the issue?

Here is the badge_circle code

```
 <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <corners android:radius="10dip" />
    <solid android:color="@color/tab_button_text_color_not_clicked" />
    <stroke
        android:width="1dip"
        android:color="#FFF" />
    <padding
        android:bottom="5dip"
        android:left="5dip"
        android:right="5dip"
        android:top="5dip" />
</shape>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the two on a LinearLayout. Framelayout may only have 1 childview

```
<FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btn_home"
        android:layout_weight="1">

<RelativeLayout
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <com.hyper.barcodeapp.customClass.CustomButton
            android:id="@+id/btn_promotions"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/promo"
            android:text="@string/promotions"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="@android:color/tab_indicator_text"
            android:textSize="@dimen/sp_16" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_badge"
            android:layout_width="15dp"
            android:layout_height="15dp"
            android:layout_alignRight="@id/btn_promotions"
            android:layout_alignTop="@id/btn_promotions"
            android:layout_gravity="top|right"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/dp_1"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dp_1"
            android:background="@drawable/badge_circle"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="@dimen/dp_3"
            android:text="10"
            android:textSize="5sp" />

</RelativeLayout>

    </FrameLayout>
```

Comment: With linear layout i can not put "txt_badge" on top right of "btn_promotions".

Comment: Ow, RelativeLayout w8

Comment: Now try this RelativeLayout

Comment: you can see just a blank space instead of any text in textview "txt_badge"

Comment: did you try to remove the margin?? If not still fine, Try to start redesigning the textView and slowly build it until you get the textView you want. bcoz I got no problem in my layout Im trying it now